# How many arrangements? $(a, b, c, d, x, y, z, w)$

Tags: combinatorics

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: How many arrangements?
[image]

My Study

I solved by mathematica11.0

```
f[n_] := {a, b, c, d, x, y, z, w} /. 
  Solve[0 < a < b < c < d < n && 0 < x < y < z < w < n && a < x && 
    b < y && c < z && d < w, {a, b, c, d, x, y, z, w}, Integers]
f[9]=490
```

Comment: Should they be all the numbers from 1 to 8, or can $b=x$ for example?

Comment: @Empy2 duplicates allowed, but ways of arranging the numbers 1 to 8 would also be an interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are counting [strictly order-preserving maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Mappings_between_partially_ordered_sets) $P\to[8]$, where $[8]$ denotes the poset $\{1<2<\dots<8\}$ and $P=[2]\times[4]$ with $(a,b)\le(c,d)$ if and only if $a\le c$ and $b\le d$:
$$
P : \quad
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
(1,1) & < & (1,2) & < & (1,3) & < & (1,4) \\
\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{<}
&& \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{<}
&& \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{<}
&& \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{<}
\\
(2,1) & < & (2,2) & < & (2,3) & < & (2,4).
\end{array}
$$
Hence, the number we are looking for is $\Omega^\circ_P(4)$, where $\Omega^\circ_P$ is the [strict order polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_polynomial) of $P$.

For the strict order polynomial, there is the formula
$$
\Omega_P(n) = \sum_{w\in\mathcal L(P)} \binom{n+\operatorname{des}(w)}{|P|},
$$
where $\mathcal L(P)$ is the set of [linear extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension) of $P$ and $\operatorname{des}(w)$ is the number of descents of the linear extension $w$ with respect to some fixed natural labeling of $P$.

In our case, we can pick the natural labeling $\begin{matrix}1234\\5678\end{matrix}$. As mentioned by @saulspatz, there are $14$ linear extensions of $P$ by the [hook length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) for counting [standard Young tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau#Tableaux). A list of these with their descent numbers is:
$$
12345678, d=0,\\
12354678, d=1,\\
12534678, d=1,\\
15234678, d=1,\\
12356478, d=1,\\
12536478, d=2,\\
15236478, d=2,\\
12563478, d=1,\\
15263478, d=2,\\
12356748, d=1,\\
12536748, d=2,\\
15236748, d=2,\\
12563748, d=2,\\
15263748, d=3.
$$
Here a descent is any position where a number is followed by a smaller number, for example in $15263478$ the descents are $52$ and $63$.

Hence, we have
$$\Omega^\circ_P(n) = \binom{n}{8} + 6 \binom{n+1}{8} + 6 \binom{n+2}{8} + \binom{n+3}{8}$$

This finally yields
$$\Omega^\circ_P(8) = \binom 8 8 + 6 \binom 9 8 + 6 \binom {10} 8 + \binom {11} 8 = 490.$$

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial solution.

The problem is somehow related to [Young tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau).  If we were required to use all the numbers from $1$ to $8$, we could compute the number of tableau of this shape with the [hook-length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula) which in this instance gives $$\frac{8!}{5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}=14$$

Here are the hook lengths:
$$5\ 4\ 3\ 2\\
  4\ 3\ 2\ 1$$
It is apparent that we can have any or all of the equalities $b=x,\ c=y, d=z$. For example, if
$$abcd\\
xyzw$$  is a standard tableau, we could replace it by either $$abcd\\byzw$$ or $$axcd\\xyzw$$  For each of the $3$ diagonals, we have $3$ choices: leave it unchanged, or make it constant in one of two ways, which brings us up to $27\cdot14=378$ solutions.

So far all our solutions have $a=1,\ w=8$, but there are others, for example $$2345\\3456$$  I haven't been able to think of a simple way to count these.

I've Googled "Young tableaux with repeated elements," but I didn't find anything bearing directly on this problem.  Admittedly, I've just spent a few minutes on this.  [This paper](https://users.math.msu.edu/users/bsagan/Papers/Old/uyt.pdf) discusses a number of variants, but a brief perusal didn't turn up anything directly relevant.

Comment: Counting descents in the linear extensions given by the $14$ standard Young tableaux, you can get the result by a descent formula for strict order polynomials of finite posets. Have a look at my answer!

Comment: @Christoph Thanks.  I'll need a little time to absorb it.  I'm pretty sick, and it may be a few days before I can get to it.   I may (probably will) have questions then.